# If, else dynamic statement logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone explain the logic behind this code?(This is the correct code btw)

```
<% if @request.query['first_name'] && !@request.query['first_name'].empty? %>
    Welcome! <%= @request.query['first_name'] %>
  <% else %>
    Hi! What is your name?
<% end %>
```

My intuition is to write the following instead:

```
<% if @request.query.inspect['first_name'].empty? %> 
    Hi! What is your name? 
  <% else %> 
    Welcome! <%= @request.query.inspect['first_name'] %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to have a user form where people can input their names, when there is no input yet the text above the form says "Hi! What is your name?" when there is an input it has a message saying "Welcome! *User_name*"

The first block of code is not intuitive to me, the second one would make more sense.. ANy advice on how to understand the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, though you need an alternative to `empty?`. Rails adds a few different methods you can use:

`blank?` returns true if the receiver is `nil`, an empty array, string, or hash, or a string with only whitespace.

`present?` returns true if `blank?` is false. So your condition could be:

```
<% if @request.query['first_name'].present? %>
  Welcome...
```

(I find it's always more intuitive to start with the positive condition - it would work just as well to check `blank?`).

**Edit**: It's pretty likely you can skip the query method entirely if all you expect there is either a string or `nil`. Just use:

```
<% if @request.query['first_name'] %>
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `if @request.query['first_name'] ` because is not equivalent to the first code, since empty strings will pass the condition and it may cause unexpected results

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin, you are correct. Implementation depends on how well-tested the codebase is.

Comment: Using .present? is not working. I get an error but doing @request.query['first_name'] works, anyone know why the .present? might not work? I get the following error message: undefined method `present?' for "blah13":WEBrick::HTTPUtils::FormData

Comment: @user3408293, what kind of error? Rails defined `present` on `Object` so there's very little on which it would raise an error.

Comment: I posted the message in the comment above yours, not sure if considered an error message but not what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it's nil before you can check if its empty, because you are checking a [Hash#empty?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-empty-3F)

```
irb(main):001:0> nil.empty?
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0> {}.empty?
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the first condition inside the if statement by transforimng nil into an empty string. I don't know if that is what you meant to do but you almost had.

First, you shouldn't call `inspect` in the hash because it will transform the entire thing into a 'complex' string. What you want to do turn only the value inside the `first_name` option, because in that case if the name exists it will still be the same, and if it doesn't, it will be turned into `"nil"`.

Secondly, the method `inspect` isn't the best choice here, because the returned string will never be empty, given that `nil.inspect => "nil"`. What you should use is the method `to_s`, wich will behave like this when applied to nil: `nil.to_s => ""`.

Finally, you could update your code to:

```
<% if @request.query['first_name'].to_s.empty? %> 
  Hi! What is your name? 
<% else %> 
  Welcome! <%= @request.query['first_name'] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `query.inspect["first_name"]` would return the literal string `"first_name"` or `nil`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to remove the `inspect` method

Comment: @ZachKemp I didn't realize he was calling `inspect` for the entire hash untill now. This is weird because it will never reach the `first_name` value, I think he meant to use `query["first_name"].inspect`

Comment: When I try to use the .blank? solution I'm getting the following error: undefined method `blank?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @user3408293 I'll update my answer to simplier form, try it and then tell me how it goes

Answer (score 0):

The code checks for hash key existence, then check if the value of the hash is present. This action can be done in one check using:

```
@request.query.try(:[], 'first_name').empty?
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try this solution: undefined method `try' for {"first_name"=>"blah13"}:Hash

Comment: then you are not using rails, why did you add it to tags?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get your question.

Comment: you added `ruby-on-rails` as a tag to your question, but if you have no `try` and `blank?` methods it is not rails.

Comment: So its only Ruby is what you are saying? I'm new at this still trying to understand the differences. My mistake.